# List view is not focussable. if i made background color as white

Tags: android, android-layout

i added background color of my layout, as white.

then i created a list by extending BaseAdapter class.
but my list item is not focusable(when i move cursor to any item it do not show focus color).

but if i remove background color tag of layout, it works fine.below is my xml layout.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" android:background="@color/color_white">

        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10px"
        android:textColor="@color/color_white"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:visibility="visible" />
</LinearLayout>
```

please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The list item backgrounds are ["State List Drawables"](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList), which define a color for different states of a view. If you set the background to just a simple color, it will be that color in all instances. You need to only override the specific "state" in the default drawable to keep the rest  of the colors intact. Here's an [example](http://daniel-codes.blogspot.com/2010/07/how-to-change-listview-rows-background.html).